# Message.ToString() returns different values when called from different Threads

Tags: c#, xamarin

I Have Xamarin Bound Service. I am recieving messages through Messenger. When I call on message ToString(). I recieve different text output. When I am on main thread and when I am on different Thread(Inside the task).

1. Question why is that happening ?
2. What is meaning of the flags: when, target, barrier ?

The code:

```
public override void HandleMessage(Message msg)
{    
    logger.Debug("!!!  " + msg.ToString());
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        logger.Debug("!!!  " + msg.ToString());
    });
}
```

Output:

```
{ when=-934ms what=1 target=md5a56ec90154194c537973c21a7ec07420.DeviceServiceHandler }
{ when=-26m4s894ms barrier=0 }
```

Comment: are you trying to get the message from the `Message` class? It seems `ToString` may not be overridden to return what you want.

Comment: msg object is coming from another app. I did not overridde ToString. Rather I am interesting why they are not same and meaning of the flags. (in the not overridden functionality)